# Which app do I need to display facebook feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to display the "wall posts" from Facebook page to another website's social media wall.

The problem is that I never used neither Facebook nor any other social networks and got no clues on how do they work. That's why I'm pretty confused with API and it's terms.

The API docs say that I need a pageId for the page I'd like to display and appId and appSecret to get an access token to the feed.

I understand how to get the token and how to parse the results - but what kind of Application do I need for that? Should I create a facebook profile and make an application that would generate me these app codes? Or ask a page's owner to do it?

I spent quite a time googling but it must be something too obvious to write about it in docs? Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The administrator of the facebook page is the only one that has access to the posts on the page wall.

**For the APP:**
The application can be created in any facebook verified account - go to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps and create the new app - this will give you the app id and secret.

Use the Facebook SDK that you feel most comfortable with to develop the app.

**For the wall posts:** There are several Graph API requests for wall posts in the form of:
`https://graph.facebook.com/[pageid]/[call]` where [call] can be posts, statuses, feed, home. See `http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6214535/what-is-the-difference-between-feed-posts-and-statuses-in-facebook-graph-api` for details about each.

Using an access token (that you said you already know how to get) the administrator of the page will be able to call the above URLs and get the wall posts.

For the part with posting the info on another social media website you have to specify the exact environment where you want the wall posts to end up.

Comment: So the process is:  I create any random application, get an accessToken from it and use the token to access the posts on a wall?

Comment: Check out this answer too: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7181475/retrieve-facebook-page-wall-posts